# Javascript multiline string causing "SyntaxError ILLEGAL"

Tags: javascript, jinja2

I have a very basic function on a template that shows an alert message:

```
  <script>
    function detailer(pii_other){
        alert(pii_other);
    }
  </script>
```

it is called with a string value like this:

```
<td><button onclick="detailer('{{other}}')">Details</button></td>
```

It works fine on most cases but I saw that it sometimes fails based on the content of 'other'. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` on the Chrome Javascript console.

[Edit:]

I am reading the `other` content from a RESTful API service that returns JSON, in this case the other field has this content:

```
body: {
    other: ""address_street"=>"江西省九江市共青城市 账号 2123123912391239 户名 齐少楠", "name"=>"test""
}
```

How can I prepare my code to support multiline strings in the alert ? I have no way to restrict the data input in the form.

Comment: how are you putting the string in? that should convert new lines to `\n`.

Comment: Multiline strings are invalid in javascript ***if they are literal***, if it's something the user inputted, it shouldn't be an issue? As you're using a Python templating engine, I'm guessing what you really mean by inputted by the user, is that it's stored somewhere, and then outputted as a literal string.

Comment: @adeneo Yes, the user inputs that somewhere, I am reading this from database and injecting it into the JS function with Jinja template, Python, as you can see in the tags.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza show that python code. thats doing something wrong.

Comment: And by injecting it into the javascript from the serverside you're effectively creating literal multiline strings somehow.

Comment: @adeneo: I know, that is exactly what I want to avoid, since I can't modify the source of the data

Comment: @DanielA.White, edited with details.

Comment: can you use a JSON stringifier?

Comment: @DanielA.White: I got JQuery and JQuery-UI in the template itself

Answer (score 0):

I would do the same thing Daniel A. White suggested - convert the new lines to some string that won't evaluate to a 'real' new line in your templating engine (Jinja?). You may have to escape the new line character so that it stays on one line.